# python terminal showing the output of another program

Tags: python, pygame

So I was following along a pygame tutorial and the code looks like this:

```
import pygame
import os
import time
import random
pygame.font.init()

player_vel = 5
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 750

BLUE_BULLETS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_laser_blue.png"))
YELLOW_BULLETS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_laser_yellow.png"))
RED_BULLETS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_laser_red.png"))
GREEN_BULLETS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_laser_green.png"))
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\background-black.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")


RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_ship_red_small.png"))
GREEN_SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_ship_green_small.png"))
BLUE_SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("C:\\pixel_ship_blue_small.png"))

YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("C:\\pixel_yellow_ship.png"))

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_image = None
        self.laser_image = None
        self.laser = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 50 ,50), 1)

def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    lives = 5
    level = 1
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)
    ship = Ship(500, 500)
    keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()

    def redraw_window():
        WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0))
        level_font = main_font.render(f"level :{level}", 1, (0, 0, 255))
        live_font = main_font.render(f"lives :{lives}", 1, (0, 0, 255))

        WIN.blit(level_font, (10, 10))
        WIN.blit(live_font, (WIDTH - live_font.get_width() - 10, 10))
        ship.draw(WIN)

        pygame.display.update()

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        redraw_window()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            ship.x -= player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            ship.x += player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            ship.y -= player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            ship.y += player_vel
        

        for event in pygame.event.get:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
                run = False


main()
```

I am pretty sure I did not do anything wrong this time.

but the output looks like this:

```
PS C:\Python\space invaders\assets\assets> & C:/Python/python.exe "c:/Python/space invaders/assets/assets/main.py"
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.12, Python 3.9.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
what is your min len gonna be?
```

It shows the pygame window but the window just stays black and you can't even close it.

Sorry if the output part is a bit messy but stack overflow won't let me post it because there is too much code.

Comment: typos: `pygame.event.get()` instead of `pygame.event.get`, but `pygame.QUIT` instead of `pygame.QUIT()`

Comment: No it still shows the same stuff which seems to be the output from another program, but thanks anyways

Comment: Why "no"? Of course, these are obviously issues in your app. However, the problem you described has nothing to do with your code. You have something messed up in your system. This question is off-topic.

Comment: I suspect one of the modules/packages you import is not what you think it is. You might have an own file called e.g. `random.py` lying around in Pythons search path and that contains an input with the text you see. Do something like `print(random.__file__)` for all of the modules after the import and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to missing parentheses in the pygame.event.get line of your code. get is a function so it should end with (). It should be pygame.event.get() instead of pygame.event.get.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
       run = False
```

Try this.